# How to set Micorosoft office 2016 applications to open in Maximised window?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I am trying to set the applications in office 2016 to open in maximized state whenever it is opened. I tried to change the properties and set it to open in maximized state. But that will work only when that particular shortcut is used to open that application, when a file is opened then the applications doesn't open in maximized state.

Can someone help me to tackle the situation?. I am running applications in windows 10.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

1. Open the application;
2. Maximize the window;
3. Close the application.

Next time you open it, the application will already be maximized.

Comment: I am looking for a method which will open the application in maximized state irrespective of the last state in which it was closed.